# Looking for Registry DEFRAGMENTATION application!

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, windows-registry, defragment

I'm looking for open source or freeware registry defrag app, preferably one who doesn't need a stupid .exe installer. .zip packed and ready to go prefered!

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PageDefrag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426.aspx) is from the Sysinternals Suite and does what you're looking for.

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to mention I'm using Windows 7

Comment: PageDefrag runs on W7

Comment: That may very well be, but I don't trust an app designed for XP/2000 registry architecture to run on Win7 registry architecture. I'm paranoid.

Comment: Not on 64bit W7.

Answer (score 1):

Well your paranoia will probably make this suggestion useless, but if you don't mind the known issues (no UAC and a minor fixable error), the venerable [NTREGOPT](http://www.larshederer.homepage.t-online.de/erunt/) will work on Windows 7...

Comment: Confirmed to work and not break anything on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: The site says to turn off UAC, but running it as an admin is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Emergency Boot CD: http://www.prime-expert.com/ebcd/

It can defragment Windows 7/Vista/XP/2000/NT4 registry in two modes: "Optimize for speed" and "Optimize for size".